# Emails are not triggering when MIME mail is selected

Tags: webforms, emails

I want to send HTML emails on webfrom submission. Gone through many tutorials as well as Questions on stack but didn't found a proper solution. 
I am using three modules to send these HTML mails.

[MIME mail](https://drupal.org/project/mimemail),[Mail system](https://drupal.org/project/mailsystem),[SMTP Authentication Support](https://drupal.org/project/smtp)

I had configured all the settings in **MAIL system** module. 
when all the the class are set to **MIMEmailsystem_SMTPmailsystem**.

[image]

Mails are being sent but am not getting "**Send e-mail as HTML**" option my webform email configuration"

[image]

When i am setting "**Webform module class**" to **MIMEmailsystem**, "**Send e-mail as HTML**" is visible but mail are not getting dispatched.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the email template format From Custom Template to Default Template or you can create your own template using place it in templates folder (/sites/all/themes/your-theme-folder/templates) and name it webform-mail-webform-node-id.tpl.php

Comment: Actually i have used a different module for this HTML email.